# how to add json object to a json element in spring

Tags: json, spring

i want to make a json object where it looks like

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "message": {
    "ID": "test",
    "Text": "Acd"
  }
}
```

i need to post this data to server i am trying to add a json object to a json object how to do it

```
            org.json.JSONObject json = new org.json.JSONObject();

            org.json.JSONObject root = new org.json.JSONObject();
            root.put("version", "1.0");
            json.put("ID", "test");
            json.put("Text", "acd");
            root.put("message", json);
```

i am getting root.put is not a method for(string,jsonobject)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `Map` for nested json object, like this:

```
Map json = new HashMap();
org.json.JSONObject root = new org.json.JSONObject();
root.put("version", "1.0");
json.put("ID", "test");
json.put("Text", "acd");
root.put("message", json);
```

According to [doc](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#put(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Map)):

> Put a key/value pair in the JSONObject, where the value will be a
>   JSONObject which is produced from a Map.